# How can I reduce the amount of "if" statements being used here?

Tags: java, if-statement

**Answered**

Thanks for the help!

I am working on some code for my AP Computer Science class and I was wondering if there is a more effective way to do this. The method is very long and redundant. Explanation alongside the improvements I can make would be greatly appreciated!

```
public void setColor(){

    if(sequenceNum == 0){
        myColor = Color.RED;
    }
    if(sequenceNum == 1){
        myColor = Color.ORANGE;
    }
    if(sequenceNum == 2){
        myColor = Color.YELLOW;
    }
    if(sequenceNum == 3){
        myColor = Color.GREEN;
    }
    if(sequenceNum == 4){
        myColor = Color.BLUE;
    }
    if(sequenceNum == 5){
        myColor = Color.MAGENTA;
    }

}
```

Comment: You should learn to solve easy problems like this by yourself before coming to sites like this. its literally as easy as googling your problem

Comment: I think this should be on Code Review instead of SO?

Comment: @MikeAgustin, no need to transfer this, as it has gotten good answers here. On [Codereview.se] this could actually be closed for being a stub code. Please read a [Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 5):

The switch statement is one idea, but if the sequence numbers are dense I would use a lookup table:

```
final Color[] myColors = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, ...};

myColor = myColors[sequenceNum];
```

after range-checking `sequenceNum` of course.

Note that your original code should have had `else` before every `if` except the first. No point in retesting after a match.

Answer (score 3):

You could do

```
Color[] colors = {Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW...};
myColor = colors[sequenceNum];
```

Answer (score 2):

The Java switch statement is what you're looking for:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

```
switch (sequenceNum) {
  case 0:
    myColor = Color.RED;
    break;
  case 1:
    myColor = Color.ORANGE;
    break;
....SNIP...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Color[] MAP_SEQNUM_TO_COLOR = {
  Color.RED, 
  Color.ORANGE, 
  Color.YELLOW, 
  Color.GREEN, 
  Color.BLUE, 
  Color.MAGENTA
};

public void setColor(){
  if( (0 <= sequenceNum) && (sequenceNum <= 5)) {
    myColor = MAP_SEQNUM_TO_COLOR[sequenceNum];
  }
}
```

**Disclaimer**: Not tested, better treat it as pseudo code. I'm more active in the C# area than with Java, but the idea should be clear, though.

Answer (score 0):

with a `switch`

```
switch ( sequenceNum ) {

case 0:
    // Do something
    break;

case 1:
    // Do something else
    break;

default:
    // Do a default something
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setColor(){
  switch(sequenceNum){
    case 0:
      myColor = Color.RED;
      break;
    case 1:
      myColor = Color.ORANGE;
      break;
    case 2:
      myColor = Color.YELLOW;
      break;
    case 3:
      myColor = Color.GREEN;
      break;
    case 4:
      myColor = Color.BLUE;
      break;
    case 5:
      myColor = Color.MAGENTA;
      break;
  }
}
```

But this is also ugly the answer provided by Reimeus is way more elegant just make sure you check that 0 <= sequenceNum <5 to avoid getting a arrayoutofboundsexception. I'm guessing you are learning so you should check the wiki for useful resources : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info. And the javadoc for more information on the control flow : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/flow.html

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

If by "reducing the amount of "if" statements" you mean literally that, then you could use a switch, but this amounts to a similar sequence of tests performed when the code runs. If, on the other hand, what you really want is to reduce the amount of tests, a cleaner solution would be to use an array (as already suggested by others), especially since your sample code implies that each color is uniquely associated with an integer.

Comment: Using a switch does not 'amount to a similar sequence of tests performed when the code runs'. It is a single indexed jump in cases like this.

Comment: @EJP Sure, if someone is aware of how it is optimized in bytecode. In the general sense, it is a way to express outcomes for different cases. But, point taken, and indeed it does not amount to that in practice.

Comment: @EJP - in small examples like this, that may not be true. I'm not familiar with the Java compiler optimisations - however, in some languages, small cases like this are actually implemented as a decision tree rather than a jump table, as the performance tradeoff is very very small.

Comment: @HarryHarrison How so? I describe two specific solutions (optimization issues aside) and explain when and why one of them might be better.

Comment: @HarryHarrison I'm a compiler writer, and these are not 'optimizations'. This is code generation 101. Switch statements are generated into (a) indexed jumps, (b) binary searches, or (c) if-else chains, depending on the sparseness. If the indexed-jump implementation wasn't fully intended from the start the statement would have no reason to exist. If you can produce a compiler that generates if-else chains for a switch statement with 6 adjacent cases please do so. I also disagree with your statement that this is a comment not an answer.

Comment: @madanasta If 'one isn't aware' of how it is 'optimized', by which I assume you mean 'generated', in byte-code, why are you making statements about how that happens?

Comment: @EJP It wasn't my intention to do so but I guess the choice of words "when the code runs" was a poor one. I was trying to imply that in general and at a syntactical level one could also "read" a switch statement as an association of pieces of code with criteria and identify which code to to execute by eliminating cases sequentially, much like a sequence of ifs. I don't disagree with your point that in this case it is not the same, hence I wrote "point taken" above.

Comment: @EJP - my masters dissertation was on the optimisation of multi-variable 'switch' statements, one of the observations from my experiments was that GCC only used jump tables in adjacent scenarios where the number of cases was larger than approx 15. As a caveat, I should say that this was many years ago, and the approach may have changed significantly in that time.  I'm not saying that decision trees are more performant, but compilers don't necessarily chose the most performant option ;)

Comment: My comment about this being a comment rather than a question was not supposed to be directed to this answer (or even an answer on this question) - too many windows open. I have removed the comment (I was also not responsible for the downvote.